# logparser binaries distribution

Tags: logparser

Is it legal to distribute the Microsoft logparser binary (dll) with my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check **C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\EULA.rtf** for **END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE: LOG PARSER TOOL**.

I think you should not distribute the binary (dll) within your application.  You can tell user to install LogParser before installing your software.