# Query EventLog on Windows Server 2003 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2003, event-log

I'm now building a Windows Event Log viewer and we have quite a few Window Server 2003 boxes. I'm using EventLogReader class to do the querying, but it requires Vista+ so cannot be run on Windows Server 2003. Although EventLog class is available but it is very slow. Any other choices do I have?

Update: I'm not querying all the event logs, instead I'm querying event logs in a date range, is there a way to make it faster given that we only need event logs fall into a range? Now using EventLog class is extremely slow even for local box, unbearable for remote one.

Comment: Unless you are building something more complex than a Log viewer, How about using something out-of-box like Log Parser Studio ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio.aspx)

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan, I don't know, we have two requirement,
#1, it must support Win Server 2003, both querying and running on, that's why I'm stuck with EventLog class since EventLogReader is not supported on Win Server 2003
#2, it needs to query over multiple servers at once
Can the two be met with Log Parser Studio?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan, I tried it out and that Log Parser Studio seems only work on log files, not on local system or remote server. Although this tool is very useful, it's not what we need. But thx anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EventLog class is slow. The speed of access depends on the size of the event log. In most server scenarios, they are allowed to get quite large before archiving. The native Windows Event Viewer also supports remote log viewing which allows you to demonstrate how slow remote log viewing is.

I think it is likely that the Entries property of an EventLog is ordered by date. That means you could implement binary search of the entries (which Linq does NOT do by default) to speed things up a ton. Here's an example of a binary search extension: [Can LINQ use binary search when the collection is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766328/can-linq-use-binary-search-when-the-collection-is-ordered)

Comment: As I have found out, the Entries collection is not exactly ordered by time, but it is instead grouped by date and the date is ordered. With your tip, I can improve the perf by an order of magnitude

Answer (score 2):

I just had a play with [logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659). Log Parser Studio that I suggested earlier is a UI for these set of tasks.

Here is a logparser query:

```
logparser.exe -i:EVT “SELECT TimeGenerated,EventID,EventType,EventTypeName,EventCategory,EventCategoryName,SourceName,
Strings,ComputerName,SID,Message FROM \\servername\Application WHERE TimeGenerated > ’2012-07-12 00:00:00′ AND EventType IN (1;2) ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC” -o:CSV -q:ON -stats:OFF >> c:\temp\Events.csv
```

Replace the '\servername\Application' with your server details.

The -i:EVT tells it to query event log.

Here is a quick [LogParser reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) that I use.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a duplicate if or related to [Which approach is better to read Windows Event log in C#? WMI or EventLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411384/which-approach-is-better-to-read-windows-event-log-in-c-wmi-or-eventlog).

In addition to the information provided by the link above consider limiting the amount of information before the log file events roll over.

Comment: ok, I admit the two are related, I'll rephrase it a bit to make my question clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can check out a [tool](http://eventanalyser.appointmentsbook.com) I wrote for logparser. It has a SQL-Like create screen that will give you good query examples you can use.

If you include LogParser in your application be careful about how you deploy it: [logparser binaries distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737377/logparser-binaries-distribution), you can see I included it separately.

> #1 why I'm stuck with EventLog class since EventLogReader is not
>   supported on Win Server 2003

I suggest you just borrow the code from [Visual Log Parser](http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/).

> #2 it needs to query over multiple servers at once

LogParser is perfect for querying multiple servers & multiple logs. It is very handy viewing all logs combined and sorting by Time or even Grouping by occurrence.

> #3  I'm not querying all the event logs, instead I'm querying event
>   logs in a date range, is there a way to make it faster given that we
>   only need event logs fall into a range?

Yes, LogParser full on fly's, faster than a speeding train! Here is how you query Evt logs by DateRange:

```
SELECT Extract_FileName(EventLog) AS EventLog, RecordNumber, TimeGenerated, EventID, EventType, EventTypeName, EventCategoryName, SourceName, ComputerName, Message FROM
\\servername\Application
WHERE TimeWritten > '2011-01-25 12:01:00'
AND TimeWritten < '2012-01-25 12:01:00'
```

> #4 I tried it out and that Log Parser Studio seems only work on log
>   files, not on local system or remote server.

Log Parser Studio is just a GUI for logparser, it should work, try this raw query (without LP Studio using LogParser directly) to get all logs in your domain:

```
LogParser "SELECT SourceName,TimeGenerated,TimeWritten,Message INTO filename.csv FROM \\Server\Application where Message Like '%mydomain.com%'" -o:CSV
```

Comment: Excellent answer. But what I want to do is query programmatically, not using some tool. But I'll check them out nonetheless.

Comment: It did the trick, thx. The perf now is much better on old systems